# CUDA: In which memory space is a fixed size array stored?

Tags: arrays, cuda

When setting up a fixed size array in a kernel, such as:

```
int my_array[100];
```

In which memory space does the array end up?

In particular, I would like to find out if such an array may be stored in the register file or shared memory on >= 2.0 devices and, if so, what the requirements are.

Comment: It isn't how the array is declared, it is how it is accessed that determines where the memory is stored.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For Fermi (and probably earlier architectures), for an an array to be stored in the register file, the following conditions must be met:

1. The array is only indexed with constants
2. There are registers available
3. Hopefully, the compiler also does some analysis to determine impact on overall performance

The reason for (1) is that register indexes are encoded directly within the SASS instructions. There is no way to address registers indirectly.

The main factors that limits the number of registers for (2) are:

- The SASS instructions contain only 6 bits for register indexing, which limits the number of registers that can be used in a kernel to 64. The actual number is 63 so one is reserved for something.
- An SM has a block of registers that are shared by all threads that are concurrently in flight.
- Registers are also needed for holding variables, so the compiler must balance register usage for best overall performance.

A potential workaround for (1) is loop unrolling. If a loop uses a loop counter as an index into an array, unrolling the loop (with `#pragma unroll` or manually) causes the array indexes to become constants as there is now a separate SASS instruction for each array access.

Based in part on this NVIDIA presentation: [Local Memory and Register Spilling](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/CUDA/training/register_spilling.pdf). The document also goes into detail about how the locations of variables and arrays affect performance.

Comment: Is it still true for the Kepler and Maxwell microarchitectures that registers cannot be addressed indirectly?

Answer (score 3):

Local arrays within a kernel, as the one you have defined are allocated in registers and in local memory when there are not enough register.

If you want allocate the array in shared memory you must specify it as follow:

```
__shared__ int my_array[100];
```

Comment: Adding the `__shared__` qualifier not only changes the storage but also changes the scope of the array from being local to a thread to being shared between all threads in the block.

Comment: So the compiler prefers to store arrays in the register file but if registers become the limiting factor for occupancy, the arrays get pushed out to local memory?

Comment: @RogerDahl As far as I know, yes, the compiler would tried use register and then local memory.